# Unable to upload artifacts from a Travis build

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to get Travis to upload artifacts at the end of my build using the documentation as found at http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/. The contents of my .travis.yml file is as follows:

```
sudo: false
branches:
  only:
  - master
language: node_js
python:
- '2.7'
node_js:
- '0.10'
addons:
  artifacts: true
env:
  global:
  - secure: "encrypted string"
  - secure: "encrypted string"
  - ARTIFACTS_DEBUG=1
  - ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=fireplacetests
  - API=dev
before_script:
- make install
- export DISPLAY=:99.0
- sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
- bash tests/serve.sh
- make install-webqa
script:
- make uitest-webqa
```

When the build finishes I see the following messages:

```
Uploading Artifacts (BETA)
$ travis_artifacts_install
artifacts version v0.7.8-9-g0908379 revision=09083791933418ce154332d7ef83bdee4330adb8
$ export ARTIFACTS_PATHS="$(git ls-files -o | tr \"\\n\" \":\")"
/home/travis/build.sh: line 73: /bin/uname: Argument list too long
/home/travis/build.sh: line 81: /bin/date: Argument list too long
$ artifacts upload
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: /home/travis/bin/artifacts: Argument list too long
/home/travis/build.sh: line 73: /bin/uname: Argument list too long
/home/travis/build.sh: line 81: /bin/date: Argument list too long
/home/travis/build.sh: line 65: -: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
Done uploading artifacts
```

I have tried looking at the contents of `/home/travis/build.sh` during the build, but cannot correlate it to the error(s) above.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be, and/or does anyone have this Travis artifact uploading thing working?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out there was a problem with the path. The docs suggest you don't need to specify any specific paths, but I found that if I added explicit paths then the upload at least attempted to work. For example,

```
addons:
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - my_path
```

allowed the upload to proceed.